# Passing input arguments via here document to bash script which runs java class where that input is needed

Tags: java, bash

Example: i have a class

```
public class MyClass0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Input 1st string");
        String s1 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Input 2nd string");
        String s2 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Input 3rd string");
        String s3 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("1st string is " + s1);
        System.out.println("2nd string is " + s2);
        System.out.println("3rd string is " + s3);
    }
}
```

and i call it from the script and pass input via here document

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/java/jdk1.7.0_21;
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;
java MyClass0;


./myscript.sh <<'EOL'
123
456
789
EOL
```

it works as intended:

```
1st string is 123
2nd string is 456
3rd string is 789
```

But if do this:

```
public class MyClass0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Input 1st string");
        String s1 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("1st string is " + s1);
        MyClass1.read();
    }
}

public class MyClass1 {
    public static void read() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s2 = reader.readLine();
        String s3 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("2nd string is " + s2);
        System.out.println("3rd string is " + s3);
    }
}
```

i got this:

```
1st string is 123
2nd string is null
3rd string is null
```

Any ideas what to do to make it work? What can i do for it to take other two arguments? I can't change the classes.

Comment: The 1st reader "consumes" the input (most likely) and you don't read everything

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have opened 2 buffered reader to process same input stream.

In MyClass0.main, you create one and read first line. Internally, the BufferedRead has read as much it could (here the full here document), returned the first line, and is ready to return the following lines without any IO acces.

The you open a second BufferedReader in MyClass1.read. Unfortunately, `System.in` is already positioned at end of file and any read will return `null`.

How to fix: 
IMHO the cleaner way is to pass the BufferedReader to MyClass1.read:

```
        ...
        MyClass1.read(reader);
    }
}

public class MyClass1 {
    public static void read(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        String s2 = reader.readLine();
        String s3 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("2nd string is " + s2);
        System.out.println("3rd string is " + s3);
    }
}
```

Comment: A better solution, following what OP already has. +1 for using same buffered reader.

Comment: Thanks, i would love to use this solution, but, as i said, unfortunately, i can't change classes, that's why i'm trying to find out if there's a way to pass arguments so it would work

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are using `BufferedReader` which buffers data for read by your application and if you want to achieve desired result with second peice of code you need to read `System.in` without buffering. Here is a method which can help you read from `System.in` without buffering anything

```
public static String readLine(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int c;
    for (c = inputStream.read(); c != '\n' && c != -1 ; c = inputStream.read()) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(c);
    }
    if (c == -1 && byteArrayOutputStream.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    String line = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    return line;
}
```